# Add tabs based on categories in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Suppose, I have N number categories which come from my REST. I want to add tabs for all of these categories. Let's see e.g. suppose in my REST response have only 2 categories it's create only two tab. if it has 5 categories then 5 tabs and so on.
And in each category tab load a list of my item for selected tab (category). 
Currently I I’ve implement it with static data using fragment. Each fragment uses a list view for loading items. But I think it’s not a right way.

[Here is an example](http://getcodesnippet.com/2017/01/17/create-tabs-menu-and-add-fragments-for-book-categories-in-the-xamarin-android-app-using-c-and-visual-studio/)

Can you please suggest me what should I use to or how can I add tab based on my category and load my list for each category?  I haven’t found TabLayout in Xamarin.android.

My Main View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is My Main Activity :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);              


            ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

            AddTab(" Favorite", Resource.Drawable.FavoritesIcon, new FavoriteItemFragment());
            AddTab(" Ice", Resource.Drawable.IceCreamIcon, new IceCreamFragment());
            AddTab(" Shushi", Resource.Drawable.SushiIcon, new ShushiFragment());
            AddTab(" Burger", Resource.Drawable.VeggieLoversIcon, new BurgerFragment());
            AddTab(" Biriyani", Resource.Drawable.BiriyaniIcon, new BiriyaniFragment());
            AddTab(" Pasta", Resource.Drawable.PastaIcon, new PastaFragment());
            AddTab(" Pizza", Resource.Drawable.PizzaIcon, new PizzaFragment());
            AddTab(" Sandwich", Resource.Drawable.SandwichIcon, new SandwichFragment());
            AddTab(" Coffee", Resource.Drawable.CoffeeIcon, new CoffeeFragment());



            //no_of_categories = allCategories.Count;   

        }

        private void AddTab(string tabText, int iconResourceId, Fragment view)
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetText(tabText);
            tab.SetIcon(iconResourceId);


            tab.TabSelected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
            {
                var fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);

                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);
                }
                e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, view);
            };

            tab.TabUnselected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(view);
            };
            this.ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        }
```

One of my Fragment View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:background="#FCD972"
    android:minHeight="25px">
  <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/itemListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And My Fragment Class:

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            FindViews();
            HandleEvents();

            items = itemDataService.GetItemsForCategory(4);

            listView.Adapter = new ItemListAdapter(this.Activity, items);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragment, container, false);
        }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please suggest me what should I use to or how can I add tab based on my category and load my list for each category? I haven’t found TabLayout in Xamarin.android.

I can't say the method you used is wrong, but if you want to use `TabLayout` in Xamarin.Android, you need to install the [Xamarin.Android.Support.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/) package together with some packages like `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`.

Then you can design your layout for example like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        style="@style/TabLayoutThemes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For more information, you can refer to this tutorial: [Xamarin Android: Working with material design TabLayout and ViewPager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34484.xamarin-android-working-with-material-design-tablayout-and-viewpager.aspx).

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. I’ve tried your way but the main problem is can’t add Xamarin.Android.Support.Design Component to my Project. It’s throw an error:

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 26.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Is there any alternate way for tabbing instead of TabLayout?

Comment: @Russell, what is your project's target version?

Comment: Compile using Android version(Target Framework) Android 6.0(Marshmallow)    Min Android version: Android 5.0 (API level 21- Lollipop)

Comment: @Russell, this package requires Android 6.0 and later. Change the target version of your project please.

Comment: @ Grace Feng - MSFT Sorry brother! I changed the target version to Android 6.0/Android 7.0. But it's showing same error.